# Summing the max count of each day in a month query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to sum the max value of each day for a given range that has a few months.  Right now I can only get the max value for each day.

```
$result = mysqli_query(
                      "
                      SELECT DATE(orderDate) orderDate, 
                      MAX(Count) maxCount
                      SUM(maxCount) sumCount
                      FROM testLocation 
                      WHERE orderDate >= '$data1'
                      AND orderDate <  '$data2' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
                      GROUP BY DATE(orderDate)
                      "
                      ,$link
                      );
```

};

Comment: This query would return a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY DATE(orderDate), MONTH(orderDate)`

To get MAX and SUM for both dates and months.